# XPath selecting the mother node while in a child node

Tags: xml, xpath, tree

So I'm trying to solve the query: "Find the names of the ships that were sunk"

and "Find the names of all the ships that were in battles"

but I'm having some problems.

I have this XML document:

```
<Ships>
  <Class name="Kongo" type="be" country="Japan" numGuns="8" bore="14" displacement="32000">
    <Ship name="Kongo" launched="1913"/>
    <Ship name="Hiei" launched="1914"/>
    <Ship name="Kirishima" launched="1915">
      <Battle outcome="sunk">Guadalcanal</Battle>
    </Ship>
    <Ship name="Haruna" launched="1915"/>
  </Class>
```

And for "Find the names of the ships that were sunk" 
I try:

```
Ships/Class/Ship/Battle[@outcome = 'sunk']
```

and get:

```
<Battle outcome="sunk">Guadalcanal</Battle>
<Battle outcome="sunk">Malaya</Battle>
```

But that is not the right result, is it. I don't know how to select the ship names while choosing the battle outcome or selecting the ships that were in battles. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to get "*Ships that were sunk*" :

```
Ships/Class/Ship[Battle/@outcome = 'sunk']
```

Make element you want to select as the last element in the path, and make criteria for that element within square brackets.

Or this way to get ship's name :

```
Ships/Class/Ship[Battle/@outcome = 'sunk']/@name
```

And to get all `<Ship>` element that has child `<Battle>` then select the ship's name, in short "*Find names of all the ships that were in battles*"  :

```
Ships/Class/Ship[Battle]/@name
```

Comment: And similarly for the a ship in battle, just check if the `<Ship>` has a child node of `<Battle>`: `Ships/Class/Ship[Battle]/@name`

Comment: yep, I was in process of typing that part :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But if I wanted to put in a condition, ships that were in two or more battles, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Ships/Class/Ship[count(Battle)>1]/@name ?

Comment: @JWiley what do you think?

Comment: Yep, that would work! Play around with XPath and your XML in question, there's a lot of free online testers you can use. http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

Comment: @nickvanderbeek you got it. That will work to get ships "*that were in two or more battles*"

Comment: Just to make sure that I got it: "Names of classes such that no ship of that class was in a battle" -> Ships/Class[Ship[not(Battle)]]/@name
Would this work? @har07

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What do you think about the one I just wrote? @JWiley

Comment: Very close. Your query is checking if there is *any* Ship in that class that hasn't had a battle. You want to check that *none* of them have battled: `Ships/Class[not(Ship/Battle)]/@name`